# KendoGrid Multi-column headers column reordering based on saved list of columns

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an array containing only the columns with the desired order for a Multi-column headers KendoGrid.
How can I iterate through all header rows to reorder them correctly?

If we don't have multiple headers with a loop like the following we can reorder the columns:

```
var newOrder = ["ShipName", "ShipCity", "ShipCountry"];
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

for (var i = 0; i < newOrder.length; i++) {
    var field = newOrder[i];

    $(grid.columns).each(function () {
        if (this.field === field) {
            grid.reorderColumn(i, this);
        }
    });
}
```

but how can we do the same with multi headers?
If we use the same code on multi headers grid we are getting a error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'locked' of undefined

example:
https://dojo.telerik.com/OWUxuGoL/2